# Show that $f_n(x):=\sqrt[n]{x}$ is Lipschitz continuous and determine the Lipschitz constants $L_n$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

The question:

Let $a>0, n\:\epsilon\: \mathbb{N} $ and let $f_n:[a,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x):=\sqrt[n]{x}$. Show that $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous and determine the appropriate Lipschitz constants $L_n$.

Now I wrote down the basic statement:

$|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|≤L_n|x-y|$

But I can't come up with any idea of how to get a Lipschitz constant, especially for all n.

Edit: I'm not allowed to use derivates.

Comment: Hint: What's the maximum value of $f_n'$ on the interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply mean value theorem. Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}$, so:
$$
\left|\frac{\sqrt[n]{x} - \sqrt[n]{y}}{x - y}\right| \leq \max_{x \in [a,\infty)}\left|\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}\right| = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}
$$
So we can choose $L_n = \frac{1}{n}a^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}$.

Note that the following theorem is used to conclude the inequality: Let $f : \Bbb{R} \supseteq D \to \Bbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then:
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right| \leq \sup_{x \in D}|f'(x)|
$$
The proof is very simple. By MVT, there exists $c \in [x,y]$ such that $f(x) - f(y) = f'(c)(x - y)$, so $\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right| = |f'(c)|$. Clearly $|f'(c)| \leq \sup_{x \in D}|f'(x)|$, so the result follows.

Comment: Could you also argue that $|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|={|x-y|}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y}}$ (difference of squares) and thus $L_n=max\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{y}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a}+\sqrt[n]{a}}$?

Comment: @luggasAI that first equality you mentioned does not hold for $n \neq 2$.